# How to prevent app from crashing when localstorage is not available?

Tags: typescript, angular, angularjs-decorator

I am using decorators for local storage from https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage, and I need to declare my variables like in sample, because decorator is not avaliable inside of functions.

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}
  @LocalStorage() public answers: string[] = new Array();
}
```

But if localstorage is not available my app will crash, so I need to make a check before I'll create it. Typescript allow only  constructor, method, accessor, or property, so I cannot make an "if" check.
How to make a check or optional variable to get rid of this error when localstorage is disabled?

> Error: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document`

Comment: You probably have to modify the source code of `angular2-localstorage` or open a new issue on their github page.

Comment: These decorators [are just wrapping functions for WebStorage constructor](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage/blob/master/WebStorage.ts#L14-L30). Create your own functions that wrap them. Or better, polyfill localStorage/sessionStorage, because you will need to fall back any way.